# geodesic polar coordinate parallel circles

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

When is it possible to have the *same* constant geodesic curvature on *all* parallels of a constant Gauss curvature  surface? EDIT: picture added.

[image: Unit tangent radius on Beltrami tracticoid]

Comment: what's a parallel?

Comment: @wspin Rings  orthogonal to all geodesics through a single point.

Comment: Oh, so you don't mean on a surface of revolution ... Then, never?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Sure on a surface of revolution as shown above but having no polar symmetry.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Sure on a surface of revolution as shown above, not periodic with respect to theta rotation.

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly, the answer is *never*.